# Trying to get propety of non-object json decode

Tags: php, json, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to make my own API, and I currently get an error when I try to decode the json request sent to the API

`Trying to get property of non-object`

This is the code I am using:

```
 $fetch = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $data = json_decode($fetch);

 $user->firstname = $data->firstname;
 $user->lastname = $data->lastname;
 $user->email = $data->email;
 $user->password = $data->password;
 $user->type = $data->type;
```

This works when I test it locally on xampp, but doesn't work when I push it to an Ubuntu server.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, php 7.2 and apache2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try and split the `file_get_contents()` and the `json_decode()` and check what the input is (add it to the question would be helpful)

Comment: I've just updated it. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: If you echo `$fetch` out - what does it contain?

Comment: An output with an empty string... `"message":""`

Comment: Try adding `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);` before the `file_get_contents()` line just in case.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I was able to fix it thanks to @jgh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using https://, not http://, that worked for me!

Hope this helps

(I also answered on your other question)